# Using ssh without appearing in w command output

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Usually when we ssh to a system, using w command any user can see all logged in users of that prticular system.

[image]

Is there a way to ssh access remote system without showing up on w command output??

Comment: No, there is not. The purpose of such a command is to show what accounts are currently using the system. What point would there be in a command _not_ showing all accounts in certain cases? That makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `w` ignores connections without a PTY. Try:

```
$ ssh hostname bash -i
```